# How do i execute solana-test-validator command properly?

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-cli, solana-program-library

When i try to execute "solana-test-validator" command in my terminal, i get error and it says:
"libcrypto1_1-x64.dll not found"
"libssl-1_1-x64.dll not found"

I searched everywhere and i looked every solana-test-validator related error things but i never be able to solve my problem.

Comment: Are you running on M1? If so, what version did you install? Also, are you running in rosetta terminal or not?

Comment: I am running on Windows 10 and i try to run it multiple terminals at the different times. I tried ubuntu, powershell and cmd. None of them worked and pretty much all of them gives error.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I solved it. The solution is in the problem. It needs those two DLL files. Therefore, find a correct version of the both the DLL over the internet and paste in the solana active-release path or if you have zoom installed, you can copy the DLLs from there.

```
Zoom Location - C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\Zoom\bin
Solana Active release - C:\Users\Asus\.local\share\solana\install\active_release\bin
```

Once you copy paste the DLLs, just start the CMD as an **admin** and run

```
solana-test-validator
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by reinstalling the Ubuntu terminal.